# GoogleSignIn 5.0.1 doesn't link under Xcode 10.3 tools

Tags: ios, xcode, google-signin

Updating from GoogleSignIn iOS SDK 5.0.1 from 5.0.0 is failing to link with Xcode 10.3 toolchain.

```
ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1100.0.33.8.0_0' Reader: '1001.0.46.4_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 10.0.1, (clang-1001.0.46.4)' for architecture armv7
```

Producer 1100.. I assume is due to being compiled with Xcode 11 toolchain? Is this intentional to force use of Xcode 11? For now have reverted to 5.0.0.

Comment: Hey @mark is this issue fixed?

Comment: Firebase v.6.12.0 release notes includes a mention on stopping support for Xcode 10.3 below
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#6.12.0

Comment: Not as far as I know, we are currently stuck on 10.3/Swift 5 due to bug our code causes in 5.1 compiler.